# Fail ansible play fast on concurrent async task failure

Tags: asynchronous, ansible

I've got an ansible play (split across several included playbooks) which looks a bit like this:

```
- name: Build packer images
  <snip>
  register: packer_run
  async: 2700 # 45 minutes
  poll: 0
- name: Do other stuff
  <snip>
...
- name: Check Packer build finished
  async_status:
    jid: "{{ packer_run.ansible_job_id }}"
  register: packer_result
  until: packer_result.finished
  retries: 30 # allow 15 mins
  delay: 30
```

Note the async task sets `poll=0` to allow subsequent tasks to run concurrently. However even if the async task fails immediately, ansible only fails once it's finished the subsequent tasks and checks on the async task status. Which is really annoying because it can take ~30 minutes to find out that the async task failed 30s in to the run.

Is there a way to preserve the concurrent behaviour but have ansible fail as soon as the async task fails?

I guess the obvious answer is "don't do the concurrency with ansible" but as this is running in a github actions workflow (which doesn't allow concurrent steps) using this approach provides a reasonable workaround apart from this "slow failure" problem.

Comment: I'm surprised that this is not getting more traction. Seems like a pretty normal usecase as soon as you dive further into Ansible. I can't even find a Issue within the Ansible tracker that handles this.

Answer (score 0):

Even though 'Build packer images' task fails immediately, the status of the task is only checked when 'Check Packer build finished' is reached.
Or 'Build packer images' logs the status in some file and other tasks read that.

We can keep 'Check Packer build finished' whenever we need to check the status. Check it multiple time at different points in the playbook. In any case if no one is checking if the task is failed, will never get that info in ansible console.

Comment: Ah, that's an interesting point. I guess I can't immediately guess what the `when:` and `failed_when:` clauses need to be to do a "if its finished and failed, fail the play, if it hasn't finished, no-op", but that is a good lead, thanks.